# Can the best-case time complexity be the same as the worst case time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

So I was given this algorithm :

```
CocktailShakerSort(A)
l = 1
r = n
while l < r do
  for i = l to r - 1 do
    if A[i] > A[i + 1] then
    swap (A[i];A[i + 1])
    end
  end
  r = r  1
  for i = r - 1 downto l do
    if A[i] > A[i + 1] then
      swap (A[i];A[i + 1])  
    end
  end
  l = l + 1
end
return A
```

and I need to find the Best-Case, Worst-Case and Average-Case Time Complexity.

Theoretically, the Best-Case is the case in which the array is already sorted.
My question is if the best case time complexity in this algorithm is the same as the worst case meaning 0(n^2), since it still has to complete the first two loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All **welcome to stack overflow**.

> best case time complexity in this algorithm is the same as the worst case meaning 0(n^2), since it still has to complete the first two loops

In short **Yes**, Best & worst T.C (Time complexity) of this algorithm is **O(n^2)**.

> Can the best-case time complexity be the same as the worst case time complexity?

Yes, there are many. For e.g. Selection sort with O(n^2) & Ω(n^2). You can check more [here](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/).

> Theoretically, the Best-Case is the case in which the array is already sorted.

As you have said, in best case (i.e. sorted array) the two loops will still run for each external iteration, doing comparison, without performing any swaps. Thus still performing O(n^2) operations.
Although if there has been a variable to check whether any swapping was done in the iteration, T.C could be reduced to O(n). i.e. At the end of first iteration of first loop we check

```
//Other loop

//Inner loop 1

if (bSwaps == false) 
    return A

//Inner loop2
```

**Explanation:**

From what I can understand from this code, outer loop runs n-1 times and first inner loop looks similar to that of bubble sort and second inner loop does the reverse of the first loop.

So for first iteration of outer loop, no. of operation would be

```
=> K1 * (n-1) + K2 * (n-2)
```

where, k1/k2 are some constant operations performed by 2 loops.

Therefore, for n iteration, no. of operation would be: *K * summation of n from 1 to n-1

```
=> K * (n^2 - n) / 2 => O(n^2)
```